# On whether a formula of KP is $\Pi_3$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

In the context of KP, is the formula $\forall w(w\in x \leftrightarrow\forall y\exists z F(w,y,z))$ $\Pi_3$ when $F(w,y,x)$ is $\Delta_0$?

Comment: Do you mean $\Pi^0_3$ and $\Delta^0_1$?

Comment: I believe in set-theoretic considerations one would just write $\Pi_3, \Delta_0$, because iirc superscript is used when writing (higher-order) arithmetical statements.

Comment: @Wojowu That seems right. I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems so:

Unwinding the expression, we get $$G(x)\equiv\forall w [(w\in x\implies \forall y\exists z(F(w, y, z)))\wedge (\forall y\exists z(F(w, y, z))\implies w\in x)]$$ $$\iff \forall w[(\forall y\exists z(F(w, y, z))\vee w\not\in x)\wedge (\exists y\forall z(F(w, y, z))\vee w\in x)]$$ $$\iff [\forall w\forall y\exists z(F(w, y, z)\vee w\not\in x)]\wedge[\forall w\exists y\forall z(F(w, y, z)\vee w\in x)];$$ this last statement is of the form $\Pi^0_2\wedge \Pi^0_3$ (using $F\in \Sigma^0_1$ for the left conjunct, and $F\in \Pi^0_1$ for the right conjunct), so is $\Pi^0_3$.

(I'm using, e.g., "$\Pi^0_3$" instead of "$\Pi_3$" because I sometimes quantify over subsets of an admissible set, so I like keeping track of the relative type I'm talking about.)